# My Git installation always refers to the wrong directory. Why?

Tags: git, heroku

I installed and re-installed Git on my Windows8 machine multiple times.  It's a long story as to why I did that.  Once I installed it at **C:\Git**  and now I have it installed at **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git**  and now I am having Git configuration problems.  My Git configuration is unable to write security credentials to Git configuration files because it thinks they are in a location that no longer exists (**C:\Git**).

Because of this, I always resort to using the GitHub GUI, but that wont work with Heroku.  So now I need help.

For example, when trying to push code to Heroku I get:

```
C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.com:signup-sheet.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.com:signup-sheet.git (push)
origin  https://github.com/djangofan/signup-sheet.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/djangofan/signup-sheet.git (push)
C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>git push heroku master
Could not create directory '/c/Git/.ssh'.
The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (__.__.__.156)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:00:0e:00:16:00:32:00:87:0c:00:c8:60:ad.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/c/Git/.ssh/known_hosts).
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Also,

```
C:\IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4\workspace\signup-sheet>git config --global user.email "djangofan@gmail.com"
error: could not lock config file C:\Git/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
```

Comment: This seems to be Windows `cmd` shell, did you try using `Git Bash` (MINGW32) ?

Comment: And did you check your PATH settings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is linked to the value of the environment variable `HOME`.

- make sure you don't have one [defined in your windows session](https://superuser.com/a/284351/141).
- <del>use the [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat#L9-L10) which comes with your [msysgit](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit)</del> ([obsolete since early 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26826359/6309))
  use the [git-cmd.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/build-extra/blob/c0f3cf5ea00415d44188294f4bca6da8def50656/installer/install.iss#L109) which comes with your [git-for-windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases):
  it will set `HOME` to the right value, and will be able to look for/ or create `%HOME%/.ssh` and other config files which reside in `%HOME%` directory.

With the old msysgit, that `git-cmd.bat` contains:

```
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
@if not exist "%HOME%" @set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
```

With the new git-for-windows, the `git.exe` is build with:

```
--cd-to-home"; WorkingDir: %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%
```

In both cases, `HOME` is set to, by default, `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`.

Comment: That fixed it for me.   I didn't expect that a Git var would be HOME rather than GIT_HOME and I was looking for the latter.  It all makes sense now.  Thanks.