# SSH error on push to an existing project Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitlab

Made all necessary steps to use the GitLab, these settings are:

1. Created a rsa as described in [this link](https://gitlab.com/help/ssh)
2. Copied the code generated in `{my key}.pub` and added this code in [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/profile/keys)
3. In my existent repository added to url with command `git remote add gitlab git@gitlab.com:ridermansb/breezenhibernateproblem.git`
4. I tried to make the push `git push -u gitlab master`

My .ssh/config

```
Host gitlab.com
  HostName gitlab.com
  IdentityFile C:\Users\Riderman\.ssh\gitlab_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Error below:

Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.com,54.243.197.170' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I made a video showing all the steps: http://www.screenr.com/euVH

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you paste the output of ssh -v git@gitlab.com here? (this contains local settings, if you are uncomfortable with that please email support@gitlab.com)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After seeing [your screencast](http://www.screenr.com/euVH), I see that you don't have a `%HOME%\.ssh\config` file.

This is important because:

- by default, ssh will look for the public/private key in `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`
- With an scp-like syntax (`git@gitlab.com:yourRepo`, with the '`:`' as separator), ssh could look in a `.ssh/config` file for the location of the actual public/private key, using `gitlab.com` as an entry in said `config` file.

Add  `%HOME%\.ssh\config` with:

```
Host gitlab.com
  HostName gitlab.com
  IdentityFile C:\path\to\.ssh\gitlab_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and your `git push -u gitlab master` will work.

[It turned out](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43208/discussion-between-ridermansb-and-vonc) it was also about setting HOME correctly:

> `%HOME%` was not correct.
> I configured the variable `%HOME%` to point to `%USERPROFILE%` locally and it worked

Mysygit [does set HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17084508/6309), but if you are using git outside of a `git-cmd` session, then it is your responsibility to set `HOME` correctly.

Comment: As home you mean? `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`, `C:` or `%windir%` ?  
`config` is a text file with this information? > My OS is Windows 8

Comment: @Ridermansb yes: `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`, if that is where `%HOME%` is set (and msysgit set that HOME by default to `%USERPROFILE%`

Comment: @Ridermansb msysgit sets `HOME`, as you can see in http://stackoverflow.com/a/17084508/6309/.

Comment: @Ridermansb Sorry, this is Windows: I meant for `IdentityFile` to reference the full Windows path. I have edited my answer. `~` doesn't mean anything in Windows. Only a full and complete path (starting with `C:\...`) will work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43208/discussion-between-ridermansb-and-vonc)