# can't pull changes from github - Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, github, ssh, pull

I tried to pull project from github to my local repository.

I generated all necessary ssh keys. And I cloned this project. but when I tried to pull changes I caught:

```
$ git pull
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of know
n hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

here is content of `.ssh`:

Directory of C:\Users\nlel.ssh

```
15.01.2014  13:35    <DIR>          .
15.01.2014  13:35    <DIR>          ..
09.01.2014  15:24             1 675 github_rsa
09.01.2014  15:24               391 github_rsa.pub
09.01.2014  13:08             1 751 id_rsa
09.01.2014  13:08               405 id_rsa.pub
15.01.2014  13:36               803 known_hosts
               5 File(s)          5 025 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  59 142 991 872 bytes free
```

They are presented at github account. And I cloned project ok.

**Solution:**

I recreated my keys. And generated them again, using key phrase.
I deleted old keys from pc and github and added new.

And all works now. Tricky point is that this repo was private.

***- Why does this happen?

 - How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: What is the command you used to clone and did u make any changes in keys after cloning?

Comment: Ok, I have included your conclusion in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ssh would only seek `%HOME%\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`

If you want ssh to pick a *different* set of keys, you need to declare those in a `%HOME\.ssh\config` file (which I don't see in your dir).

That `config` file would include something like:

```
Host github
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile C:\path\to\.ssh\github_rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Rename the url of your '`origin`' remote with a:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url origin github:yourName/YourRepo.git
```

This is needed for pushing (writing to) a GitHub repo that you own.
You wouldn't need ssh keys at all for pulling (reading) from a *public* repo.

---

In the [OP nazar-art](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1498427/nazar-art)'s case, the keys weren't probably the right ones, and recreating those was enough:

> I recreated my keys. And generated them again, using key phrase.
>   I deleted old keys from pc and github and added new.

Comment: Does it have to be `config.txt` file? And user I guess have to be me?

Comment: @nazar_art no just `config`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20596571/6309 for instance.