# Permission denied (publickey) when pushing commit to amazon ec2

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-ec2

I know that a lot of similar questions exist here (and I read a lot of them before posting this one), but this one is different, so please stay with me for a while.

Few days ago I configured my remote git repository on amazon ec2. After hours of struggling I made it working and was able to `push` files there. I was working with it for a day or two pushing resources to it without any problems (I saw every update properly).

Today, for some reason I can not push anything to it from my local machine.

`git push deploy` ends up with the following error message (the same one I see when I try to get info about deploy: `git remote show deploy`):

> ```
> warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
> Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
> and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:
>
>   git config --global push.default matching
>
> To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:
>
>   git config --global push.default simple
>
> See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
> (the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
> 'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)
> ```

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The first part of it (before permission denied) I was able to see previously, but it was still pushing everything correctly back then.

Deploy exist because I can clearly see it with `git remote -v`:

```
deploy  ssh://ubuntu@X.X.X.X/home/ubuntu/repo (fetch)
deploy  ssh://ubuntu@X.X.X.X/home/ubuntu/repo (push)
```

I can correctly ssh to my server, also my private key has `0400` permissions. On both machines I have `ubuntu 12.04 LTS`.

I thought that may be there is some problem with my public key, so I went ahead and recreate it from private key: `ssh-keygen -y -f key.pem > key.pub`. Based on its `sha` it is identical to my previous public key: `sha1sum key_prev.pub` = `sha1sum key.pub`

I still went to the server and added a new key to authorized keys as well.

Still no changes. I can not push anything. Can anyone tell me what is the problem here and why it happened? Do I need to do anything with my local `.ssh/known_hosts`?

Also in one of the answers I found the following:

> Please note that after restarting the instance, the dns name changed.
>   I fell for this several times. The keyfile was still valid, but the
>   "servername" changed.

I actually restarted my machine, so I think this is highly relevant. The problem is that I can not understand what should I change now.

**After reading the answer of VonC.**

I can not ssh to the server by doing `ssh ubuntu@X.X.X.X` (I got `Permission denied (publickey).`), but I can do this with `ssh myAlias`, where myAlias is defined in `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host            myAlias
Hostname        X.X.X.X
User            ubuntu
IdentityFile    path/to/mypem/file.pem
```

When I have done `git config --global push.default simple` I have another problem when doing `git push deploy`:

> fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch. To push the
>   current branch and set the remote as upstream, use
>
> git push --set-upstream deploy master

I will try to do  `ssh -Tvv ubuntu@X.X.X.X` and will tell how it goes.

Comment: When you get `Permission denied ` what is the log generated at `/var/log/auth.log` on your instance?

Comment: @clement89 Here the output of tail. `timestamp username CRON[31495]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
timestamp username CRON[31495]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do yourself a favor, and type `git config --global push.default simple` in order to not see the first part of the error.

Second, if you can login successfully with `ssh ubuntu@X.X.X.X`, then your keys are fine, as well as the instance name.

If you can not, you can:

- try a `ssh -Tvv ubuntu@X.X.X.X` to see what is going one, and
- verify that by going to the server, [stopping sshd](https://askubuntu.com/a/114684/5470) and restarting it in debug mode (`/usr/sbin/sshd -d`): it will receive only one ssh connection: try a ssh ubuntu@X.X.X.X from your client, and you should see the sshd response.
  Then restart `sshd` normally.

---

In your case, you *have* to use your alias, defined in `~/.ssh/config`, since your key isn't a standard one.

For the push to go smoothly, do a `git push -u deploy master`.

Since `git remote -v` returns:

```
deploy  ssh://ubuntu@X.X.X.X/home/ubuntu/repo (fetch)
deploy  ssh://ubuntu@X.X.X.X/home/ubuntu/repo (push)
```

That means you **are not** using the ssh alias.

Type:

```
git remote set-url deploy myAlias:/home/ubuntu/repo
```

(The syntax is important: `myAlias:` followed by the repo path)

And then try again the `git push`.

Comment: `ssh -Tvv myAlias` is working correctly, `git push -u deploy master` generates the same error with permission denied.

Comment: this is amazing, this fully solved the problem. Thank you. Can you please explain why your magic works? The thing is that I previously was able to everything with my previous `git push`.

Comment: @SalvadorDali your ssh url must use an scp syntax (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/14423667/6309) if you want your `~/.ssh/config` to be taken into account, as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/20596571/6309.