# ssh to remote pc in the same network - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, permission-denied

I am trying to install git on a remote server and these are the details of that pc

```
IP 192.168.1.7 
Ubuntu version 12.04 32 bit
```

and I have install both openssh and the status of the ssh is this

```
ssh start/running, process 756
```

And I am trying to ssh to that pc from local pc and these are the details of my local

```
IP 192.168.1.4
Ubuntu version 12.04 64 bit
```

I have ping to the 192.168.1.7

```
rashendra@rashendra:~$ ping 192.168.1.7
PING 192.168.1.7 (192.168.1.7) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.7: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.918 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.7: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=1.02 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.7: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=3.78 ms
^C
--- 192.168.1.7 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.918/1.908/3.782/1.326 ms
```

which means I can connect to that pc , and the connectivity is alive.

I have generate the rsa public/private key which are stored in `the /home/rashendra/.ssh`

```
rashendra@rashendra:~/.ssh$ ll

total 20
drwxrwxrwx  2 rashendra rashendra 4096 Nov 17 11:37 ./
drwxr-xr-x 47 rashendra rashendra 4096 Nov 17 08:35 ../
-rw-------  1 rashendra rashendra 1679 Nov 17 10:57 id_rsa
-rwxrwxrwx  1 rashendra rashendra  401 Nov 17 10:57 id_rsa.pub*
-rw-r--r--  1 rashendra rashendra  444 Nov 17 11:45 known_hosts
```

After that I copied the content of the `id_rsa.pub` to the `authorized_keys` in the `.ssh` of the remote pc

```
cat /tmp/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

This is the `.ssh` of the git user which I created.
So, now I am trying to connect to the remote pc using

```
ssh git@192.168.1.7
```

yet gives the following error:

```
rashendra@rashendra:~/.ssh$ ssh git@192.168.1.7

Permission denied (publickey).
```

Please advice how to resolve.
As I need to install git on this remote server and maintain further.

Answer (score 1):

Check [your permissions](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html):

- on the client side (`chmod 644 ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`)
- on the [server side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19798820/6309)

  ```
  chmod 700 /home/git/.ssh
  chmod 600 /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```

Then, if it is still not working, check the output of:

- on the client side, a `ssh -Tvvv git@192.168.1.7`
- on the server side, a debug ssh daemon session (`/usr/sbin/sshd -d`): see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740720/6309).

Comment: hi, This is what I got after running /usr/sbin/sshd -d
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key': Permission denied
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key': Permission denied
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
debug1: could not open key file '/etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key': Permission denied
Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug1: setgroups() failed: Operation not permitted
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'

Comment: debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-d'
Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0 failed: Permission denied.
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Permission denied.
Cannot bind any address.

Comment: how ever I did the vice versa, creating a rsa keypair in the remote server and append the public key to the authorized_keys in my local machine .. Guess what I was able to open ssh terminal as well as install git on my local pc( 192.168.1.4)...
only difference which I am seeing here is that my ubuntu is 64bit thr remote pc is 32

Comment: @Rashendra-Rashen the sshd must be run as root

Comment: yes I did , yet it did not change the out come... I still cant ssh from my local pc to the remote server.