# git pull request failed with “Permission denied (publickey)” error

Tags: git, github, ssh-keys, git-pull

I have tried to pull my official repository to my local machine using

```
git pull git@github.com:x/x_project_management_app.git master
```

but it failed with error

```
    Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have regenerated and added my system ssh-public key to my github account,I tried with different  system also,but I'm still facing same error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your public/private key is:

- set with the default names `id_rsa`, `id_rsa.pub` (instead of `id_rsa_github` for instance)
- set in `~/.ssh` (or `%HOME%\.ssh` on Windows, with `HOME` defined by [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat))
- set [with the right permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26967270/6309).

See more at the GitHub page "[Error: Permission denied (publickey)](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/)".

Answer (score 0):

Using git bash instead of Windows command line worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to give the git correct permissions

```
sudo chmod 777 .git/FETCH_HEAD
```