# Added SSH key to Gitlab but it still asks for my credentials

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, permission-denied

GitLab's HTTP pull & push are working when I enter my credentials.

But when using an added SSH key, it is always is asking for my password, which I don't know. Why is GitLab doing this? Is it a server fault?

And when calling `ssh -vT git@git.com` there is an error:

> Permission denied (publickey)

I've tried everything, even re-installing Git, but nothing works. Even their own solution is not working, as described here: https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey/

Comment: SSH key has passphrase, may it asks for passphrase ?

Comment: I suppose `git.com` is a fake name for your GitLab server? What OS are you using as a client accessing to your GitLab server? What version og Git are you using? Are the permssion ok (as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26967270/6309, I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/28793643/6309).

Comment: Wait, are you using github or gitlab? They're completely different, unrelated (though visually and functionally similar) things.

Comment: I`m using my domain name instead of git.com

I`m using linux(can`t specify OS because of my companies politics) on my server. And as client - it`s Ubuntu 14.04. Git version is 1.9.1.

Yes, permissions are okay. And I`m using gitlab!!

Comment: Then try the debug options I propose in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26967270/6309: `ssh -Tvvv git@git.com` and `/usr/sbin/sshd -d` on the server.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, after checking

```
/var/log/auth.log
```

I got :

```
*User git not allowed because account is locked
*input_userauth_request: invalid user git [preauth]
*Connection closed by IP.IP.IP.IP [preauth]
```

So the fix was

> **sudo passwd -d git**

Thanks to [Noah (source)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/26022#note_20478658)

Answer (score 2):

I had similiar problem with new installation of gitlab. After some investigation I've seen below message shown in 
systemctl status sshd:

> Accepted publickey for git from 10.x.x.x port 50858 ssh2: RSA 67:01:..
>
> User git from 10.x.x.x not allowed because none of user's groups are listed in AllowGroups

Adding git user into sshusers group solve my problem.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is a superold question, but I will post this regardless.

In my case it was an SELinux issue. Either disable it or ensure that authorized_keys has the SELinux type of `ssh_home_t` with

`semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

Where `/home/git` is the path the git user's home directory. Mine was `/var/opt/gitlab/`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using git@gitlab.com:.... instead of https://gitlab.com/... protocol.

I think this is the reason your key is not being used for authentication.

Comment: For anyone reading this who doesn't know how to change the protocol for their repo, the command to use is `git remote set-url`. (Blatant self-promotion) I wrote an answer about it for a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67527810/10634604