# GIt access issue

Tags: git, netbeans, github, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to clone a git repository. I am able to do it successfully from the netbeans IDE but if I try to use the command line to clone the repository with the same ssh private key, I am getting the following error : 
Cloning into 'name'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa': 
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

The repository exixts as I am able to clone it from Netbeans.I am using the same private key id_rsa. I am working on ubuntu 14.04.

Has anyone faced this problem. I am not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: There is almost certainly something different between the two.

Comment: ssh only prompts for a passphrase after it has tried to read the key without a passphrase and failed. The key may have a passphrase, or the file may be corrupt, or file permissions may prevent reading it.

Answer (score 0):

If your private key is passphrase protected, it is possible that said passphrase has been filled in the [NetBeans Git authentication setting](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#github) (which means NB won't ask you anything):

[image: https://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/74/ide/git/github-repo-small.png]

In command line, [you would need an ssh agent](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/90853/7490) in order to memorize the passphrase.

Comment: I haven't given any passphrase while creating the key.So I do not give anything in netbeans either.In command line I just press enter.

Comment: @user3679348 are your permissions properly set on the ssh folder and keys? As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/26967270/6309?

Comment: They were different, I set them now to the one as in the answer but no luck.Still getting the same issue

Comment: is there any place where a log will be generated on my system on this issue ?

Comment: @user3679348 you can generate one with `ssh -Tvvv`, as in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22740720/6309.

Answer (score 0):

There must be a passphrase when you generate you ssh key, just enter it when the information

> Enter passphrase for key '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa':

appear.

Comment: @ younghz I hadn"t given any passphrase while creating the keys.