# Build Git server

Tags: git, ssh

I'm building my own git server on centos, I have done all these steps:

I add a new user named git and it's home is /home/git

and then I use ssh-keygen -t rsa to generate the .ssh

then I edit the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file to open the pub_key authorization :

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
```

then I git init --base in /srv/remote.git

finally I generate the id_rsa.pub on my client and copy it to my git server: /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

but when I git clone the repository : git@ip:/srv/remote.git

it always asks me to enter password, so why?

Comment: Does your ssh client use the key you authorized for the git user? As a check, you must be able to `ssh git@git_server` without a password. Try `ssh -vv -i ~/.ssh/the_generated_key.pub git@git_server` to force the use of the generated key, and to view every step of the ssh connection.

Comment: @9000 I tried ssh git@localhost:/srv/remote.git but it comes error :Could not resolve hostname localhost:/srv/remote.git: Name or service not known

Comment: You need just the host part, not the path (the `:/srv/...`). It's just a regular ssh connection.

Comment: @9000 I tried ,it asks me the password

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug what is going on:

- check the ssh sesion on the client:

  ```
  ssh -Tv git@ip
  ```
- check the logs on the server (`/var/log/auth.log`)
- check also the [ssh daemon session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22740720/6309) to see what it does on the server when you do the ssh from the client ([stop sshd](https://askubuntu.com/a/114684/5470), then restart it for a one-time connection with `sshd -d`)