# How to fix Permission denied (publickey,password) in gitlab Ci/CD?

Tags: ssh, gitlab

I have below simple script in .gitlab-cl.yml file:

```
build_deploy_stage:
  stage: build
  environment: Staging
  only:
    - master
  script:

    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh

    - echo "$PRIVATE_KEY" >> ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_dsa
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
    - cat ~/.ssh/config
    - scp   myfile.js user@example.com:~
```

But I get this error when job is run, executing the last line (scp command):

```
Warning: Permanently added 'example.com' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

I spent whole day but could not fix it. I verified that $PRIVATE_KEY exists.  I generated key pair while logged into example.com copying the generated private to PRIVATE_KEY variable on gitlab.
How to fix this problem?

Note that it is dsa key.

Comment: Try running `ssh -vvv user@example.com` and [edit] your question to include the verbose output which ssh produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your permission for `~/.ssh` (700) and all the files in them (600)

Your config file, for instance, might have default permissions that are too large.
If you can, [activate a debug session in the sshd of the remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41844152/6309): you will see if an dsa key is accepted (for recent version of sshd, that might be restricted). rsa would be better.
As [seen here](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23385), OpenSSH 7.0 and higher no longer accept DSA keys by default.

The [OP ace](https://stackoverflow.com/users/574122/ace) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247092/how-to-fix-permission-denied-publickey-password-in-gitlab-ci-cd/52251390#comment91454238_52251390):

> I fixed the problem when I regenerated tsa key pairs instead of dsa keys

Comment: I fixed the problem when I regenerated tsa key pairs instead of dsa keys

Comment: @ace tsa? Or did you mean rsa?