# Authorizing to my git server with `.ssh/authorized_keys` does not work

Tags: git, ssh

I setup a git server 2.30.2 on my NAS with debian bullseye.

User is `git` with home directory `/media/nas/programming/git_repos/` and shell `/bin/bash`.

home directory and all of its subdirectories/files are owned by `git:git`.

home directory has `770` permissions and directory `.ssh` inside home directory has `700` permissions.

I create a private/public key with command `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C mymail@gmail.com` (or on second try `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C mymail@gmail.com`).

Public key becomes `/media/nas/programming/git_repos/.ssh/authorized_keys` (`git:git` ownership, 400 permissions) and private key becomes `c:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519` (or on second try `c:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa`) on Windows PC.

On `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` I have a line `AllowUsers root git ...`

Now, with Git GUI, I am trying to connect to remote (lets say fetch) with url `url = git@10.0.0.2:my_project`.

Initially it asks for password to decrypt `id_ed25519` (or on second try `id_rsa`).

Then it asks for password for `git@10.0.0.2` which means Git server does not count at all the `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

What I am doing wrong here?

**update** `ssh -Tv git@10.0.0.2` does not say so much:

```
 ....
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
 debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\chameleon/.ssh/id_rsa
 debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\chameleon/.ssh/id_dsa
 debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\chameleon/.ssh/id_ecdsa
 debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\chameleon/.ssh/id_ed25519
 debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
 Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\chameleon/.ssh/id_ed25519':     <---- Here I give the password
 debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
 debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\chameleon/.ssh/id_xmss
 debug1: Next authentication method: password
 debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
 git@10.0.0.2's password:    <---- Here I give the password. After that, connection established.
```

Comment: hmm.... I think again: is StackOverflow appropriate for this question?

Comment: `ssh -Tv git@10.0.0.2` ?

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com is probably more appropriate.

Comment: @chepner thanks. People already anwser. Is it proper to delete this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to my question:

**Fast:** Change permissions of `git` home folder from `770` to `750`.

**Bloated:**

As @VonC says above, I start a new `sshd` instance in port `12345` with debug `3` mode:

```
sshd -p 12345 -ddd
```

Then I replace my remote repository link inside `MyProjectFolder/.git/config`, from:

```
[remote "MyNAS"]
        url = ssh://git@10.0.0.2:my_project
```

to

```
[remote "MyNAS"]
        url = ssh://git@10.0.0.2:12345/~/my_project
```

and I try a `fetch`.

`sshd` instance respond that `git` home folder does not have properly ownership and/or permissions.

I change `git` home folder from `770` to `750` and now it works.

PS: group writing set, because I `user` belong to `git` group and I was feeling that write access to git repo is a handy permission. Never mind. It is not so useful.

Comment: Well done. Upvoted. Permissions are important indeed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the [right permission](https://superuser.com/a/1559867/141) on the remote side (NAS ~git): if anything if writable by "others", SSH will not consider the `authorized_keys` file.

Then test your connection with `ssh -Tv git@10.0.0.2` and confirm your `c:/Users/<username>/.ssh/id_ed25519` is considered and proposed.
If it is, consider launching an [sshd in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41844152/6309) on your NAS to see if any error message pops up during your `ssh -Tv` test command.