# SSH connection refused from Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I am using Gitlab CI to build a static generated website and send it to my server. I am using a SSH keys pair to establish the connection from rsync, but my server is refusing the connection.

I tried several things: started with ED25519 key, changed to RSA key, all public keys are in authorised_keys in the server, changed permissions in files and folders by gitlab-ci.yml, used ssh-keyscan to put the servers in know_hosts... nothing help.

The gitlab-ci.yml is the following:

```
image: ruby:2

pages:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install rsync -y
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - chmod 400 "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  - ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - ssh-keyscan $SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d $LOCALDIR
  after_script:
  - rsync -paz $LOCALDIR $USER@$SERVER:$REMOTEDIR
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $LOCALDIR
  only:
  - master
  - dev
```

Part of log output is the following:

```
$ rsync -paz $LOCALDIR $USER@$SERVER:$REMOTEDIR
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
$SERVER: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(228) [sender=3.2.3]
```

Well, any help or tip in this topic?

**EDIT 1 - SSH logs**

Thank you @Andrew. I used the `ssh -vvvvvv ...` option as suggested and this is an extract of the output:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /root/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

So, maybe the command `ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"` in gitlab-ci.yml is not working as expected.

**EDIT 2 - the answer**

Thank you to @VonC the tip to copy the SSH private key fixed the problem. Following the final `gitlab-ci.yml` working as expected:

```
image: ruby:2

pages:
  stage: deploy
  before_script:
  - apt-get update
  - apt-get install rsync -y
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
  - cp "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
  - ssh-keyscan $SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  - chmod 644 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
  script:
  - bundle install
  - bundle exec jekyll build -d $LOCALDIR
  after_script:
  - rsync -auz --delete --omit-dir-times $LOCALDIR $USER@$SERVER:$REMOTEDIR
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - $LOCALDIR
  only:
  - master
  - dev
```

Comment: Can you add `ssh -vvvvvv $USER@$SERVER exit 0`, assuming your using account is not restricted to rsync, and show relevant logs?  Also, do you have acces to server in question to check sshd logs? `journalctl -u sshd` should help

Comment: @user I have added a workaround in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75877529/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure to use a private key *without* passphrase, which means you do not need the `eval $(ssh-agent -s)`.
Pipelines normally do not interact well with passphrase to be set during an ssh connection.

Second, double-check the corresponding public key is properly added to the remote server `~$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

Using `ssh -Tvv $USER@$SERVER` can help on the pipeline side to check if your key is actually used.
And you can start a [`sshd` in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41844152/6309) on the remote server side to check you are actually receiving SSH queries.

---

> maybe the command `ssh-add "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY"` in `gitlab-ci.yml` is not working as expected.

As an alternative, copy your key with a default name:

```
cp "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
```

That way, it will be selected, without needing the `ssh-agent`.

Comment: Thank you @VonC, the tip to copy the private key fixed the problem. Now rsync is working as expected. I will add my final gitlab-ci.yml in the question. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

- only one step is necessary ..
- ( the examples below are with rsa also in filenames , you could use ed25519 as well )
- since you will have you key in a variable SSH_PRIVATE_KEY it "should" work like this ( but read below)

  ```
  after_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends bash rsync openssh-client && ( echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" > /tmp/id_rsa && chmod 0600 /tmp/id_rsa )  &&  ssh-agent bash -c "test -e ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh; ssh-keyscan $SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts;ssh-add ~/tmp/id_rsa; rsync -paz $PWD $USER@$SERVER:$REMOTEDIR "
  ```

this might fail(multiline string),
so i recommend to base64-encode your key ( `base64 -w0 ~/.ssh/id_rsa ;echo` )

```
  after_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends bash rsync openssh-client && ( echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" |base64 -d > /tmp/id_rsa && chmod 0600 /tmp/id_rsa )  &&  ssh-agent bash -c "test -e ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh; ssh-keyscan $SERVER >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts;ssh-add ~/tmp/id_rsa; rsync -paz $PWD $USER@$SERVER:$REMOTEDIR "
```

(

- in fact you could also leave out the ssh-agent when you put the key under `~/.ssh/id_rsa` **BUT it needs to have the 0600 permissions**
- you can also try `head -c 120 /tmp/id_rsa` to see if the content starts with the proper values
  )