# git clone using ssh failed in Windows due to permission issue

Tags: linux, git, unix, github, ssh

I have created a new GIT repository in my server at `/home/myuser/.git/project.git`.
I found ssh key for git from `C:\Users\Toshiba\.ssh\github_rsa.pub` & appended with server's `authorized_keys` file.

when i try to do git clone using ssh it fails as below.

> $ git clone ssh://myuser@mysite.net:2888/home/myuser/.git/project.git

```
Cloning into 'project'...
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Could you please help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your public/private key doesn't have the standard name `C:\Users\Toshiba\.ssh\id_rsa(.pub)`, but `C:\Users\Toshiba\.ssh\github_rsa.pub`, then you need an ssh config file

```
Host mysite
   Hostname mysite.net
   User myuser
   Port 2888
   IdentityFile C:\Users\Toshiba\.ssh\github_rsa.pub
```

That would allow you to do

```
git clone mysite:/home/myuser/.git/project.git
```

Test it first wih `ssh -Tvvv mysite`, and then `ssh mysite ls`.

Make sure the environment variable `%HOME%` is defined to `C:\Users\Toshiba`

You have another example in "[SSH error on push to an existing project Permission denied (publickey)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20596571/6309)"