# git ssh ask for a password with gitlab

Tags: linux, git, ssh, gitlab, chmod

I have recently installed on my Ubuntu dedicated a Gitlab server.

Webapp is working fine, I had no trouble during the installation (tested on VM before production environment)

I have uploded my ssh rsa private key from the web app on my account, and created a project, clone from another repository.

From my desktop environment, I have tried to git pull using ssh.
First login, I had to accept the ssh fingerprint, then, until now server keep asking me to log in as git user, which has no password.

```
D:/drive/project> git pull git@0.0.0.0:me/project.git
git@0.0.0.0's password:
Connection closed by 0.0.0.0
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

D:\skydrive\artmoser>git pull
git@0.0.0.0's password: [tried to type something]
Permission denied, please try again.
git@0.0.0.0's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@0.0.0.0's password:
^C
```

My ssh public and private key under windows is in  C:\Users\Jack Bauer.ssh
On the dedicated server I can see my key in /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys

I have checked my chmod for user git :

```
drwx--x--x  7 git     git     4096 mai   31 05:06 git/
drwx------  2 git  git  4096 juin   1 03:27 git/.ssh/
-rw------- 1 git git  508 juin   1 02:53 git/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

What am i doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

After more research :

If I log in with git user with putty, I receive this error message `server refused to allocate pty`

If I try to do `ssh git@0.0.0.0`, they ask for my passphrase, 3 times before git user password (which has none)

If I do a ssh tunnel with `ssh git@0.0.0.0 -Tvvv` , i get this errror at the end of the log

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/me/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

Comment: it may be a typo; anyway, you should copy your **public** key in the authorized keys file.

Comment: I did a mistake, the public key is on my computer, the private is on the server, I'll correct

Comment: Does *ssh git@0.0.0.0* work?

Comment: I have only a windows computer, I have linux binaries but not ssh, I could do a telnet, I can't tell you

Comment: Are you sure git does not ship with *ssh*?

Answer (score 3):

> the public key is on my computer, the private is on the server,

If you want to access a server with ssh, your client (here your Windows workstation) must have **at least** the private keys (and it is a good practice to keep the public keys together with their private keys counterparts).

```
C:\Users\Jack Bauer\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
C:\Users\Jack Bauer\.ssh\id_rsa
```

If your keys don't follow this default naming convention, you will need a [`C:\Users\Jack Bauer\.ssh\config`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15551505/6309) file (as [illustrated there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7550935/6309))

Make sure you have the `HOME` environment variable set to `C:\Users\Jack Bauer` in your Windows shell when you are typing those command: [that is the case if you launch the `git-cmd.exe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17084508/6309) (which comes with any [Git For Windows distribution](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

Comment: I did place the two files with the exact same name, I had to remove my github ssh key. I still can't log in, but now he ask me for a passphrase for key. I didn't set one, so I had to make a new key, but it still reject the passphrase.

Comment: @BigDong no need for passphrase, make sure you have a private key without a passphrase (for testing purpose), and that your public key is published on the server side in the `~git/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: @BigDong then you can debug ssh as illustrate in http://stackoverflow.com/a/23173608/6309 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/22740720/6309

Comment: Thanks for the links, but still, i can't ssh in command line, with windows, I have to use putty. Using putty with the ssk key with git@maserver:22 return this error "server refused to allocate pty", and putty close

Comment: @BigDong you were able to ssh to GitHub though? (before moving your GitHub keys). Note that you can have multiple sets of ssh key with a config file (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7550935/6309)

Comment: @VonC actually, having just the private key on the client is sufficient

Comment: @guido while that might be true technically, the best practice would be to keep both closely together on the client (or you have to `ssh-keygen -y` each time you want to publish your public key: http://askubuntu.com/a/53555/5470).

Comment: /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys has the option "no-pty", so it should be correct that putty doesn't work.

Comment: @BigDong see Vincent's comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976078/git-ssh-ask-for-a-password-with-gitlab/23976901?noredirect=1#comment39207894_23976901

Comment: @Vonc that's true, however, "our client [...] must have both public and private keys" is broadly different from "the good practice is that".

Comment: @Jocelyndelalande I agree and I have amended my answer accordingly